# PHP fsockopen error, connection refused(111), try to connect fingerprint device using TCP/IP

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, fingerprint, fsockopen

i was want to connect to my fingerprint device useing TCP/IP
i was setting ip address in device,

my php code:

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("192.168.1.211", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

when i try to connect, i get error `connection refused` . but ping to device is work, i don't know where is the problem,

My fingerprint device specification:

```
Vendor :Solution
type : x101-c
```

i hope somebody can help and solve my problem,,
i really stack now....

Answer (score 3):

> but ping to device is work

Ping uses ICMP packets not TCP. If you're getting a connection refused then the (TCP) port is firewalled.

Comment: is it becouse of cable problem ? or anything else ?
by the way,, thank you for your answer